Does dotnet framework version of MagicOnion.Client, support Windows Server 2022?
I use dotnet framework version of MagicOnion.Client for call .net core version of magiconion.server.
When I call server from windows 11, I don't get error.
But When I publish my client project on windows server, after call grpc, I get below error.

Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. WinHttpException: Error 12029 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A connection with the server could not be established'.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12029 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A connection with the server could not be established'.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable1.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequestAsync>d__122.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall2.d__82.MoveNext()")

Windows specifications
Edition Windows server 2022 datacenter
version 21H2
OS build 20348.2402
Does dotnet framework version of MagicOnion.Client, support Windows Server 2022?

magic.client has not any problem.
problem is from my legacy code(.net framework). I got error when I called grpc in Task.Run like below code.
        public class MyClass
    {
        private readonly IMyGrpcService _myGrpcService;
        public MyClass()
        {
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("GrpcAddress");
            return MagicOnionClient.Create<IMyGrpcService>(channel);
        }

        public void CallGrpc()
        {
           return Task.Run(async () => await _myGrpcService.CallGrpc()).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
}

Top code get 12029 error on server. I changed that as below and solved my problem.
public class MyClass
{
    private IMyGrpcService GetGrpcService()
    {
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("GrpcAddress");
        return MagicOnionClient.Create<IMyGrpcService>(channel);
    }

    public void CallGrpc()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => await GetGrpcService().CallGrpc()).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

